# error when running a-- cross-compiled executable

Tags: cross-compiling, libcrypto

I have cross compiled vscpd program
Following is the backtrace from GDB. Here i am not getting what is causing this SIGILL
which terminates the program.

Does this error means --> libcrypto.so.1.0.0  --> shared library file contains illegal instruction ?

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ gdb vscpd
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.4.1-debian
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "arm-linux-gnueabihf".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...
Reading symbols from /home/pi/vscpd...done.


(gdb) break main
Breakpoint 1 at 0xee0c: file vscpd.cpp, line 99.


(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/pi/vscpd 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libthread_db.so.1".
Program received signal SIGILL, Illegal instruction.
0x400fc4c0 in ?? () from /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcrypto.so.1.0.0



(gdb) bt
#0  0x400fc4c0 in ?? () from /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
Cannot access memory at address 0x0
#1  0x400f8ee4 in OPENSSL_cpuid_setup ()
   from /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
#2  0x4000f250 in ?? () from /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3
#3  0xbefff96e in ?? ()
Cannot access memory at address 0x0
#4  0xbefff96e in ?? ()
Cannot access memory at address 0x0
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)
```